# Выравнивание элемента по центру

Tags: html

Друзья, я хочу выровнить элемент по центру, но у меня не получается из за вот такой вещи:

1.Перед началом работы я все обнулил:

```
* { padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0; }
```

2.Потом я пишу такую вещь, которую и хочу выровнять:

```
<div class="content white" id="content">
    11
</div>
.content{
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 1000px;
    float: 0px auto; 
}
```

Выравниваю через маргин - ауто, но он не работает, ругается что я уже поставил маргин в начале. Подскажите, как поступить в этой ситуации? Сказать, что просто не обнулять по дефолту - не подходит. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: float: 0px auto; уберите это. Оно точно не выровняется по центру, флоат только поддерживает определенную сторону (лево, право...) - центральную часть не поддерживает. А маргин: 0пк авто, должен работать, так как он изменяет для этого элемента параметры. Если не помогло есть другие способы

Comment: А вы как пишите, я бы рекомендовал попробовать `margin: 0 auto;` Может вы пишите `margin: auto;`

Comment: @oldzas, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом), в противном случае, опишите Вашу проблему более подробно.

Answer (score 2):

Всё без проблем работает с `margin:0 auto`.

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/YTkgh/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 0):

Вы определитесь, либо `class` либо `id`? А то пишете `class="content white"  id="content"`, а потом обращаетесь к нему `.content`. За дело минусуют.

Вашей страничке самое место вот [здесь](http://www.govnokod.com/).

Comment: Какая разница? Ну хочет человек использовать и `class`, и `id` одновременно — что в этом плохого?

Answer (score 0):

*HTML*

```
 <div class=“example”>
         Lorem ipsum....
 </div>
```

*CSS*

```
.example{
     margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="content white" id="content" align="center">
    11
</div>
```

Это для html 4.01

Comment: Не пишите больше такого.

Comment: В чем дело то? Для html4 синтаксис проходит валид. и при этом работает. А вы еще минусуете, а самому что-то написать не судьба?

Comment: 1. Вы ответили, не поняв суть вопроса: нужно выравнить блок по центру, а не его содержимое.

2. Такое использование одинарных кавычек крайне не рекоммендовано в `html`. Во-первых, некрасиво смотрится использование обоих кавычек одновременно, во-вторых, возникают проблемы при использовании одинарных кавычек в `php`, но это отдельная тема.

3. Использование свойства `align` крайне не рекоммедовано. В целях оптимизации, желательно выносить всё, что возможно, в отдельный `CSS`-файл. Чем больше исходный код страницы — тем с большим трудом будет обрабатывать страницу поисковик.

Comment: валид ругается, а на доктайпе html4 нет. Можете проверить

Comment: @Node_pro, хорошо, тогда за доктайп - извините. Но это не меняет тогопунктов 1-3, которые я писал.

И еще: ходить по моих вопросах и ставить минусы — как-то низко. Мы же серьезные люди, а не дети, пытающиеся "как-то задеть" :)

Comment: После Вас, я пошел по такому методу, мне терять не чего как и вам? Верно? Плюс я сказал вариант, какой может действительно работать. И кстати чтобы Вы знали, align - он выравнивает обьект, но не как текст внутри, проверьте. Насчет оптимизации не спорю, но всеже он попросил рабочий вариант верно?

Comment: Атрибут `align` выравнивает сам обьект, а не текст? Простите, что? Советую изучить *[материальную часть](http://htmlbook.ru/html/div/align)* перед тем, как кому-то что-то советовать.

Comment: А да извините, ошибся. Почему-то думал что эффект такой же как и с таблицой будет.